# Converting Datatable to ienumerable<anonymous>?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

is it possible to convert data table to ienumerable without know its class name.

my requirement is to convert table

```
First | Last
--------------
john  | mcgill
clara | linda
```

to

```
{{First:john,Last:mcgill},{First:clara ,Last:linda}}
```

Ienumerable collection

i dont want to use dynamic object because dynamic object supports only frame work 4.

thanks

Comment: Just read your comments. What do you need this for? Is it visualization (e.g. a grid view)?

Comment: @Alan: yes i need it for grid

Comment: In that case, you truly can't use anonymous types. If you're using WPF, doesn't hooking up the DataTable to a standard WPF DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns=true do what you want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var results = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
              select new {
                  First = row.Field<string>("First"),
                  Last = row.Field<string>("Second")
              };
```

You'll need `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

Comment: yes i know this way but based on my requirement i dont column name at compile time . i will know at run time only

Comment: is any other way ? i head banged with this

Comment: @YogeshWaran If you don't know the names of the columns at compile-time, then you can't get your anonymous type to have its field names match the column names. It is the compiler that generates the anonymous type, and thus needs to know the field names. One approach would be use Reflection Emit to generate the type at run-time; you can read up on that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kyyyeh2.aspx

Comment: @YogeshWaran: No, that's impossible. Given what you said in your comment, you can't use anonymous types. Anonymous types are emitted by the compiler at compile time; to use them you must know at compile time the names. You can't use dynamic, per your requirements. Therefore, use a collection of property bags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) - they were introduced with .NET 3.5.

Syntax for that kind of objects is really clear and intuitive:

```
var item = new { First = "First-Value", Last = "Last-Value" }
```

and the query:

```
var items = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(i => new {
                                           First = i.Field<string>("First"),
                                           Last= i.Field<string>("Last")
                                      });
```

Comment: yes i know this way but based on my requirement i dont column name at compile time . i will know column name and select new object properties at run time only

Answer (score 1):

No column names please!

```
    public string ConvertDataTableToString(DataTable table)
    {
        int iColumnCount = table.Columns.Count;
        int iRowCount = table.Rows.Count;
        int iTempRowCount = 0;
        string strColumName = table.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        string strOut = "{";
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) 
        {
            strOut = strOut + "{";
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                string val = row.Field<string>(col.ColumnName);
                strOut = strOut + col.ColumnName + ":" + val;

                if (col.Ordinal != iColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    strOut = strOut + ",";
                }
            }
            strOut = strOut + "}";
            iTempRowCount++;

            if (iTempRowCount != iRowCount)
            {
                strOut = strOut + ",";
            }
        }
        strOut = strOut + "}";
        return strOut;
    }
```

Comment: Just added this to test that the column value is not null: 
    string val = row.Field<string>(col.ColumnName); changed to
(used vb.net)
    Dim val As String = String.Empty
    If Not IsDBNull(row(col.ColumnName)) Then val = row(col.ColumnName)

Answer (score 0):

It is a fairly easy job using anonymous types. Here is a complete example that only requires classes from the System.Linq and System.Data namespaces:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
      dataTable.Columns.Add().ColumnName = "First";
      dataTable.Columns.Add().ColumnName = "Last";
      var row = dataTable.NewRow();
      row["First"] = "hello";
      row["Last"] = "world";
      dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

      var query = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .Select(r => new
        {
          First = r["First"],
          Last = r["Last"]
        });

      foreach (var item in query)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.First, item.Last);
    }
  }
```